# How to load 5 pages without refresh with side bars on drupal

Tags: ajax, module, drupal-7, content-management-system

i am newbie to drupal, 
Now i am  working in Drupal CMS. 
Now i need to place 5 nodes(pages) contents in one page without refresh and without effect the parent page side bar.

like this below link
[Sample Website For Ajax Loading](http://www.mindtree.com/services/application-development-maintenance-adm)

How could i achieve this kindly help me

click the link and go down little to find tabs.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one. This module is serving as you specified.
https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_website